# does dbe.forum module exist in django

Tags: django

Is this module deprecated? What is the replacement for it, if so?

Django Version: 1.6
Python Version: 2.7.6

The following is stack trace:

```
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  320.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  222.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  229.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  100.                     not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named dbe.forum
```

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your code you try to `import dbe.forum`. Make sure you have `dbe` listed under `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings, or remove any reference to the `dbe` module in your models/views/forms code.